# How do I sort an array of structs by multiple values?

Tags: sorting, swift

I already have code to sort by 1 value as shown below, but I'm wondering how to sort using multiple values? I would like to sort by set and then by someString.

One is an integer, and one is a string in this case. I had considered converting the integer to a string and then concatenating them, but thought there must be a better way because I may have 2 integers to sort by in the future.

```
struct Condition {
    var set = 0
    var someString = ""
}

var conditions = [Condition]()

conditions.append(Condition(set: 1, someString: "string3"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 2, someString: "string2"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 3, someString: "string7"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 1, someString: "string9"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 2, someString: "string4"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 3, someString: "string0"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 1, someString: "string1"))
conditions.append(Condition(set: 2, someString: "string6"))

// sort
let sorted = conditions.sorted { (lhs: Condition, rhs: Condition) -> Bool in
    return (lhs.set) < (rhs.set)
}

// printed sorted conditions
for index in 0...conditions.count-1 {
    println("\(sorted[index].set) - \(sorted[index].someString)")
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not yet proficient in Swift, but the basic idea for a multiple-criteria sort is:

```
let sorted = conditions.sorted { (lhs: Condition, rhs: Condition) -> Bool in
    if lhs.set == rhs.set {
        return lhs.someString < rhs.someString
    }
    return (lhs.set) < (rhs.set)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Even though the previous answers are perfectly fine in the requested case, I'd like to put a more general approach for that:

```
infix operator <=> {
associativity none
precedence 130
}
func <=> <T: Comparable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> NSComparisonResult {
    return lhs < rhs ? .OrderedAscending : lhs == rhs ? .OrderedSame : .OrderedDescending
}
private func _sortedLexicographically<S: SequenceType>(source: S, comparators: [(S.Generator.Element, S.Generator.Element) -> NSComparisonResult]) -> [S.Generator.Element] {
    return sorted(source, { lhs, rhs in
        for compare in comparators {
            switch compare(lhs, rhs) {
            case .OrderedAscending: return true
            case .OrderedDescending: return false
            case .OrderedSame: break
            }
        }
        return false
    })
}
public func sortedLexicographically<S: SequenceType>(source: S, comparators: [(S.Generator.Element, S.Generator.Element) -> NSComparisonResult]) -> [S.Generator.Element] {
    return _sortedLexicographically(source, comparators)
}
extension Array {
    func sortedLexicographically(comparators: [(Element, Element) -> NSComparisonResult]) -> [Element] {
        return _sortedLexicographically(self, comparators)
    }
}
```

from here it's quite easy to do an ordering like requested:

```
struct Foo {
    var foo: Int
    var bar: Int
    var baz: Int
}
let foos = [Foo(foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3), Foo(foo: 1, bar: 3, baz: 1), Foo(foo: 0, bar: 4, baz: 2), Foo(foo: 2, bar: 0, baz: 0), Foo(foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 2)]
let orderedFoos = foos.sortedLexicographically([{ $0.foo <=> $1.foo }, { $0.bar <=> $1.bar }, { $0.baz <=> $1.baz }])
```

If this kind of comparison for that type is intrinsic to the type itself instead of being an one place-only sorting you need, you can follow the more stdlib-like approach and extending `Comparable` instead:

```
extension Foo: Comparable {}
func == (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    return lhs.foo == rhs.foo && lhs.bar == rhs.bar && lhs.baz == rhs.baz
}
func < (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    let comparators: [(Foo, Foo) -> NSComparisonResult] = [{ $0.foo <=> $1.foo }, { $0.bar <=> $1.bar }, { $0.baz <=> $1.baz }]
    for compare in comparators {
        switch compare(lhs, rhs) {
        case .OrderedAscending: return true
        case .OrderedDescending: return false
        case .OrderedSame: break
        }
    }
    return false
}
let comparableOrderedFoos = sorted(foos)
```

There would be another possible approach which is making a `LexicographicallyComparable` protocol which says which `Comparable` fields and in which priority they do have, but unfortunately I can't think of a way to make it without using variadic generics, which are not supported in Swift as 2.0,  while maintaining the type safety typical to Swift code.

Comment: This is the correct approach, IMHO. If you are going to define a struct, and you want to be able to compare it, it's the struct that defines it's ordering

Comment: Indeed, I agree. But there still could be cases where you want to show an alternative sorting order and you would want that possible. As they say: YMMV

Comment: Extra points should be awarded for having demonstrated the use of Swift custom operators as well as type generics to solve this problem! Bravo!

Comment: Amazing answer!  In Swift 2, sorted has changed to sort, and it is now called on the collection, i.e.: source.sort(...

Answer (score 6):

You would compare `someString` if the `set` values were the same, otherwise, use your existing comparison:

```
let sorted = conditions.sorted { (lhs: Condition, rhs: Condition) -> Bool in
    if lhs.set == rhs.set {
        return lhs.someString < rhs.someString
    } else {
        return lhs.set < rhs.set
    }
}
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks!